# Create dropdownlist using select tag helper of a view model in .NET Core Razor Pages (Not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Say I have this models: Movie

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }        
}
```

and I have this view model

```
public class MovieDateHallSeats
{
    public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

and I have create a .NET Core Razor Page (Not MVC) to populate the list of movies.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Cinema.WebCore.Data.CinemaContext _context;

    public CreateModel(Cinema.WebCore.Data.CinemaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        MovieDateHallSeats movieDateHall = new MovieDateHallSeats();
        movieDateHall.Movies = _context.Movies.ToList();

        ViewData["MovieId"] = new SelectList(movieDateHall.Movies, "Id", "MovieTitle");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I managed to get this run so far and see the movie count here. But my problem is, how to I create the dropdownlist using the select tag helper?

In my Razor Pages, I have this below at the moment.

```
  <select asp-for="?" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MovieId"])">
                <option value="">Pick one</option>
  </select>
```

By the way, I can easily create/scaffold views of my view models in .NET Framework but .NET Core Razor Pages, I can't seem to find the option to scaffold Razor Pages of a view models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with this syntax

```
<select asp-for="MovieId" asp-items="ViewBag.MovieId">
    <option value="">Pick one</option>
</select>
```